# How to limit the characters that can be used with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to limit the characters in flutter I want to know, even if I looked it up, I could only find out how to limit the keyboard, such as only numbers and emails.

Is it possible to limit the characters that can be used, such as numbers + letters + @, etc.?

Please tell me, thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`FilteringTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[A-Za-z0-9@]"))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The above text field will allow the user to only type letters, numbers and the `@` character.